# Cash.c Expected 18/n not 22/n

Tags: c, cs50

I can't seem to figure out whats wrong with my code, but I'm receiving incorrect values for simple inputs like 1 or 2 but correct inputs for .41. If someone could help me out It'd be greatly appreciated!

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <math.h>
int main(void)

{
    //Establish Variables
    float amount_owed;
    int c = 0;
    //Get Valid Input from User
    do
    {
        amount_owed = get_float ("Change Owed: ");
    }   while (amount_owed <= 0);

    //Check for quarters, mark  # of quarters that can be used, subtract value from original amount_owed
    do
    {
        (c++);
        (amount_owed = amount_owed - .25);
    }   while (amount_owed >= .25);

    //Check for dimes, mark # of dimes that can be used, subtract value from original amount_owed

    do
    {
        (c++);
        (amount_owed = amount_owed - .1);
    }   while ((amount_owed >= .1) && (amount_owed < .25));

    //Check for Nickels, mark $ of nickels that can be used, subtract value from original amount_owed

    do
    {
        (c++);
        (amount_owed = amount_owed - .05);
    }   while ((amount_owed >= .05) && (amount_owed < .1));

    //Check for Pennies, mark # of pennis that can be used, subtract value from original amount_owed

    do
    {
        (c++);
        (amount_owed = amount_owed - .01);
    }   while ((amount_owed >= .01) && (amount_owed < .05));
    //Print Number of Minimum number of coins that can be used

    {
       if (amount_owed == 0)
       ;
        printf("%d\n", c);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please define what you mean by "incorrect values".  It's most likely that your program is suffering from floating-point error.  If you are trying to do precise calculations in cents, it's generally better to use integers.

Comment: Work out on paper what your logic does with a value of 1. Do you check if you any quarters before you change the value? A do/while loop is the wrong choice here.

Comment: Yes, another vote for integers.  With integers you are guaranteed perfect accuracy.  Besides, with ints you can use the rounding behavior of division and the modulo operator which makes the logic generic for any coin value.

Comment: It's recommended to never use floating point types to handle currency. They have precision limits, and tend to round numbers in unexpected and often disastrous ways. This is likely the reason why you are having problems.

Comment: @Havenard: It is not recommended to **never** use floating-point for currency. Floating-point is useful for calculations involving more than simple arithmetic, such as stock market options valuation. A proper recommendation is that a programmer should always understand the tools and techniques they are using.

Answer (score 0):

To start with you should never use float for somethin that need to be accurate. But let's get back to that later as there is another issue with your program.

For now just assume that float is actually precise.

When you write:

```
do
{
    c++;
    ...
} while(...);
```

the code in the body will **always** be executed **at least once**.

So with your code if the input is `1.0` the first loop will be executed 4 times and `amount_owed` will be `0.0`.

When for the next 3 `do-while` you will still go into the body once and do the `c++` (even though `amount_owed` is zero). Consequently you result will be 7 instead of 4 (that 4 from the first loop + 1 from each of the three following loop).

The solution is to use regular `while` instead of `do-while`. Like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    float amount_owed = 1.0;
    int c = 0;

    while (amount_owed >= 0.25)
    {
        c++;
        amount_owed = amount_owed - 0.25;
    }

    while ((amount_owed - 0.1) >= 0)
    {
        c++;
        amount_owed = amount_owed - 0.1;
    }

    while (amount_owed >= .05)
    {
        c++;
        amount_owed = amount_owed - .05;
    }

    while (amount_owed >= .01)
    {
        c++;
        amount_owed = amount_owed - .01;
    }

    printf("%d\n", c);

    return 0;
}
```

Back to using **float** : floats can't represent every number 100% accurate. So when doing calculations involving floats, you will likely see some rounding errors. So for any calculation that need an accurate result, you should try to do it using integers.

For a task like this the "trick" is to consider `amount_owed` as being in units of the lowest coins you have. Typically that means 100 times the "normal" way of thinking about it. For instance, instead of `1.17` you use `117`.

Then your code could be more like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    unsigned amount_owed = 100;  // note 100 instead of 1.0
    int c = 0;

    while (amount_owed >= 25)  // note 25 instead of .25
    {
        c++;
        amount_owed = amount_owed - 25;
    }

    while ((amount_owed - 10) >= 0)
    {
        c++;
        amount_owed = amount_owed - 10;
    }

    . . .
```